# asp.net mvc razor submit button with code in the cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, submit

I am new to MVC. Not sure how to NOT have the page do a full blinking refresh on click of the submit button. Have not found examples on this other than to put the code in an action in my controller, and I would prefer to have the code as I have it below. Thank you for your assistance!

```
<form method="post">

    <div style="float: left">
        Enter the number of days previous to today for which to search: <input type="text" name="NumberOfDays" value="@Request.Form["numberOfDays"]"/>
    </div>

    <div class="puck-button">
        <input type="submit" value="GO!" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>

    @{
        var numberOfDays = int.Parse(Request.Form["NumberOfDays"].IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? "0" : Request.Form["NumberOfDays"]);
        var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-numberOfDays);

        <table id="puckBoard" class="gridView">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ProcessSteps)
                {
                    <th>
                        <div class="puck-step">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </div>
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if(startDate != DateTime.Today) { @CompactTableRows(startDate, Model.Modules) }
            else
            { @GetSimpleModuleTableRow(Model.Modules) }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</form>
```

Comment: Huh? What's the question? You want AJAX?

Comment: Sure. I just don't know how to incorporate it with MVC Razor.

Comment: Do a search for asp.mvc and ajax. Lots of stuff out there.

Comment: I have done. All that I find suggests adding an Action in a Controller. I don't want to do that. I want it all done in my .cshtml file.